# Верно ли препинание?

Tags: пунктуация

«...не томи душу, скажи, что делаешь.» Отрывок из анекдота.

Стоит ли ставить запятую перед *скажи*? Прям просится...

Comment: Для справки. В сети практически везде так:  "Мужик, ну не томи душу! Скажи, что делаешь?!"

Comment: я немного подредактирвала...

Comment: Запятая перед *скажи* не вызывает сомнений, чего не скажешь о запятой после *скажи*. Вот где тема для обсуждения!

Answer (score 1):

...[ты] *не томи душу, скажи, что делаешь.*

Не просто "стоит ли ставить запятую перед **скажи**?", а ***обязательно, нужно*** ставить запятую перед **скажи**: два однородных сказуемых ("не томи" и "скажи") разделяются запятой.

Примеры из словарей ([**В. И. Даль**;](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/364258) [**Д. Н. Ушаков**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1055234)):
***Не томи*** меня, **скажи** правду!
*Да **не томи** ты **душу**, **рассказывай** скорей!*

*Мокеев, **не томи, скажи**, зачем один вернулся ты?*
М. Булгаков. Минин и Пожарский